# Облегчить часть кода на LAravel

Tags: laravel

Подскажите как облегчить эту часть кода ? Выполнить меньшим кодом

```
    $statuses = Statuses::where('base_id', $request->id)->get()->first();

    $carbon_date = Carbon::parse($statuses->call_date);
    $carbon_date->addHours(8);

    Statuses::where('base_id', $request->id)->update(['call_date' => $carbon_date]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так

```
$statuses = Statuses::query()->where('base_id', $request->id)->first();

$statuses->update([
    'call_date' => Carbon::parse($statuses->call_date)->addHours(8)
]);
```